# How to clear a label using tkinter when pressing a button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using labels to show a generated password in my tkinter password generator program, but when I change the length of a password from a lower value than before (for example from a length of 20 to 10) the label displaying the password appears to be overwritten - it does not clear. I have searched methods to do this, but I cannot seem to find any.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
import string

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Password Generator")
topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
root.geometry("1000x1000")

title = Label(topFrame, text="Length", fg="blue")
title.grid(row=3,column=5)

var = DoubleVar()
Slider_1 = Scale(root,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=32*10,from_=0,to=32, variable 
= var)
Slider_1.pack()
passLen = var.get()

uppercaseLetters = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"
lowercaseLetters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
symbols = "!£$%^&*()_+-=}{][~@#':;?>/.<,"
digits = "1234567890"

def gen():
    characters = uppercaseLetters + lowercaseLetters + symbols + digits
    password = "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(int(var.get())))
    passLabel = Label(topFrame, text=password)
    passLabel.grid(row=4, column=5)

    genButton = Button(topFrame, text="Generate Password", fg="blue", 
    command=gen)
    genButton.grid(row=1, column=5)

    root.mainloop()
```

When I set the length to 32 characters:

[image: screenshot]

And when I set the length to 6 characters it does not clear the old password label - it simply overwrites it in the middle of the old password label:

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: You have to destroy the old label. Else it just creates a new one.

Comment: Right okay, thanks for the comment, but how do i go about doing that ?

Comment: Better idea: create the passlabel at the begging globally, but don't use .pack; then in the gen function, just set the text and call the pack method. Should I write this or do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll give it a try, thank you for the quick response

Comment: Actually, yes I would prefer you to write as i have not used global before, thanks

Comment: You don't have to use the global keyword, but i wrote the code anyway.

Comment: Yes, your changes work perfectly, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change two things:
First:

```
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
passLabel = Label(topFrame)
root.geometry("1000x1000")
```

Second:

```
def gen():
    characters = uppercaseLetters + lowercaseLetters + symbols + digits
    password = "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(int(var.get())))
    passLabel.config(text=password)
    passLabel.grid(row=4, column=5)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, move your `gen` method definition to just below `import`s so that they're recognized in the main body. Then take your widgets and `mainloop` out of the method. Just configure `passLabel`'s text when needed:

```
def gen():
    characters = uppercaseLetters + lowercaseLetters + symbols + digits
    password = "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(int(var.get())))
    passLabel['text'] = password
```

Entire code with suggested edits been made:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
import string

def gen():
    characters = uppercaseLetters + lowercaseLetters + symbols + digits
    password = "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(int(var.get())))
    passLabel['text'] = password

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Password Generator")
topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
root.geometry("1000x1000")

title = Label(topFrame, text="Length", fg="blue")
title.grid(row=3,column=5)



var = DoubleVar()
Slider_1 = Scale(root,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=32*10,from_=0,to=32, variable 
= var)
Slider_1.pack()
passLen = var.get()

uppercaseLetters = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"
lowercaseLetters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
symbols = "!£$%^&*()_+-=}{][~@#':;?>/.<,"
digits = "1234567890"

passLabel = Label(topFrame)
passLabel.grid(row=4, column=5)
genButton = Button(topFrame, text="Generate Password", fg="blue", 
command=gen)
genButton.grid(row=1, column=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"How to clear a label using tkinter when pressing a button?"*

Below is an example that clears `label`'s text when the `button` is pressed:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def clear_widget_text(widget):
    widget['text'] = ""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(root, text="This will be cleared.")
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Clear",
                                    command=lambda : clear_widget_text(label))
    label.pack()
    button.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

---

Below is an example that destroys `label` when `button` is pressed:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def clear_widget(widget):
    widget.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(root, text="This will be cleared.")
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Clear",
                                    command=lambda : clear_widget(label))
    label.pack()
    button.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```